# fabrics on image editor mobile device

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I want to make a simple image editor (drag, rotate, resize) in javascript. It has to work at tablet and mobile phones.

Fabric seems to be very fast. The only problem is that rotating / resizing don't work  intuitive (sometimes you click and nothing happen). Does anybody know there is a solution for this in Fabric.

Or is there a other fast platform to create a fast editor

[fabric example rotating resize](http://fabricjs.com/bounding-rectangle/)